# Delete Excel Rows using vba on the basis same values in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have to delete the row if two column values are same. If Column B and Column D Values are same Then I have to delete that row. I am using one method but it is taking so much of time. Is there any other way to do it

```
Dim i As Long
For i = lngLstRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value Then
    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Use the helper function in the linked answer to `Union` all the rows together and then delete in one step at the end. In your case use `EntireRow` instead of `EntireColumn` when deleting.

Comment: Hi , I have see that topic , Could you please elaborate the same?

Comment: I am not able to get how I should implement the same in my code